# MVC get img url from controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a simple page which loads an image from the server folder but the image is not showing up.

Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
<script src="~/contents/css/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        setInterval(function () { getimg() }, 3000);

        /* code here */
    });
    function getimg(){

        $.ajax({
            url:"/Promotion/imageName",   
          type: 'Post',
          success: function (result) {

          },
          error: function (result) {
          }
      });
    };


</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div>

    <img src="@Url.Content("~/misc/uploads/"+Url.Action("imageName"))" />
  </div>
</body>
```

This is my controller to get the image name. My view page is Index page:

```
 public ActionResult imageName() 
    {
        string imgName ="chrysanthemum.jpg";
        return Content(imgName);


    }
```

Comment: Do you see the image when you put the URL in your browser: /Promotion/imageName

Comment: Or have you tried the URL with /misc/uploads/`imagename`?

Comment: it return nth<img src="/misc/uploads/">. But the code did went to the imageName

Comment: i tried hardcoding with <img src="~/misc/uploads/chrysanthemum.jpg"> and the image did shows up

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult ImageName() 
{
    string imgName ="chrysanthemum.jpg"; 
    var dir = Server.MapPath("/uploads");
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, imgName);
    return base.File(path, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: hi. thanks. but this return me  /misc/uploads/promotion/imageName.imageName supposed to be chrysanthemum.jpg

Comment: image folder is at  /misc/uploads/chrysanthemum.jpg

Comment: What do you mean it returns that? It returns a file at that location?

Comment: You might have to adjust my code slightly for whatever your path is but this is how you would return an image

Comment: is my html writing correctly? by using @URL.action("ImageName").result should return the chrysanthemum.jpg instead of promotion/imageName

Comment: When you run the debugger is the image being returned? Can you browse to the URL and get the image back in the browser?

Comment: the image src should be src="/misc/uploads/chrysanthemum.jpg" instead of src="/misc/uploads/promotion/imagename". Imagename is my actionResult and promotion is my controller name

Comment: in debugger it returns"c:\\users\\myname\\documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\ktSlides\\ktSlides\\uploads\\chrysanthemum.jpg" which is correct folder. but i tot in webpage should only show "/misc/uploads/chrysanthemum.jpg"?